# How to link custom domain to Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I created a new AKS cluster with the Application Gateway Ingress Controller add on and can access the cluster via a public IP address.

How do I then link a custom domain I have purchased to that IP address in Azure?

I've updated the nameservers on my domain (Was done a few days ago)...

[image]

I've tried adding this DNS zone record pointing to the app gateway...

[image]

I've also tried adding a DNS entry in the control panel of my domain supplier

[image]

This is what `nslookup` returns...

[image]

But nothing loads when I put this address in the browser. If I do a curl I get `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.oconnorevents.co.uk`

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the picture I see here, you pointed your DNS NS records to Azure, but then you added the A record to your registrar and not in Azure.

You have two options:

1. You add a new DNS registration in Azure (as I guess you did because you have the 4 DNS server names) and you add the A record in there
2. You remove the NS records in your domain registrar and you add the A record in there

Comment: Hi @Luca. The second screenshot shows I added an 'A' record to Azure as well, pointing to the App Gateway resource. I didn't think I needed to add this as well to my domain provider as the name servers have been transferred over but I added it anyway, just to see whether it would work.